# How to notify group of subscribers that is dynamically changing?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm working on a data mining project that needs to cluster subscribers and send some information to an appropriate subset of them.

Assume that each time we've identified the right group, how can I change the subscribers group at run time?

Should I use Observer pattern or not?

Is there any other approach?

Details:
working with ASP.net MVC for presentation and SQL Server for data mining

Comment: That sounds like a job for... [Reactive Extensions](https://rx.codeplex.com/)!